# Why closing websocket connection in Chrome by javascript is not immediately?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, frontend

I tried to use rxjs `webSocket` to connect server. When I use `.complete()` function, the `closingObserver` is triggered immediately. But I received `CloseEvent` is almost 1 minute later.
So, how can I get the `CloseEvent` immediately?

Here is an example.

```
class SomeService {
  private wsSource$ = webSocket({
    url: "ws://xxxxxx.com/api/v1/xxx",
    openObserver: this.openObserver,
    closingObserver: this.closingObserver,
  });

  connect() {
    this.wsSource$.subscribe({
      next: (e) => console.log(e),
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log("complete!!!")
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.wsSource$.complete();
  }
}
```

1. After `connect()`, Chrome will log the `CloseEvent` after almost 1 minute.
2. It is not logged by observer `complete` function, it is logged by `error` function.

Comment: Could you add a code example?

Comment: I added an example  @RenanBronchart